# Need to set up yup validation which is not required and works on only one condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I added yup validation in the date picker so what is happening now if I click on submit it says field required **Invalid Date!** but my task needs to set validation such like the error will generate only if the date is greater than today's date that I have added in max and also it is not added in any **.required("Required!")** thing but not sure why it's working as Required! field which I don't need to set as Required!

```
const today = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  date_of_birth: yup
    .date()
    .max(today, "DOB cannot be greater than today's date")
    .typeError("Invalid Date!")
});

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const IndivisualForm = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      date_of_birth: null
    },
    enableReinitialize: true,
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
    }
  });
  const handleChangeDate = (date) => {
    IndivisualForm.setFieldValue(
      "date_of_birth",
      moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    );
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <Grid container justifyContent="space-around">
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={IndivisualForm.values.date_of_birth}
          error={Boolean(IndivisualForm.errors.date_of_birth)}
          helperText={IndivisualForm.errors.date_of_birth}
          onChange={handleChangeDate}
          maxDate={today}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change date"
          }}
        />

        <Button
          color="primary"
          variant="contained"
          type="submit"
          onClick={IndivisualForm.handleSubmit}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

[Code SandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-llp06?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about why `max` should work here?

Ideally when you wanted to test out some comparison . They have [test](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestoptions-object-schema) method there. So basically you need to do this:

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  date_of_birth: yup
    .date()
    .nullable()
    .notRequired()
    .test(
      "Is date greater",
      "DOB cannot be greater than today's date",
      (value) => {
        if (!value) return true;
        return moment(today).diff(value) > 0;
      }
    )
});
```

Here is live demo codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-kbxlz?file=/demo.js

Or directly see here:
https://kbxlz.csb.app/

Comment: but this does not solve my issue

Comment: It behaves like a Required field but I need to pop an error if it greater than today date otherwise no need to pop error

Comment: I am not sure. Its popping only when you select date greater than today otherwise it wont popping. Can you explain more?

Comment: I am saying like it's not Required field error will throw when the date is greater than today that you can see in yup validation schema but it behaves like required field mean if user not select any date user are able to submit it not a compulsory field

Comment: I have updated the code. This should work if you dont want to validate if date is not selected and it will validate only when date is not selected